# Select id_seller that has all different products SQL

Tags: sql

I have these tables: `Table1` and `Table2`. I want, that the output is the `seller_name` and `id_seller`, where the `id_seller` has only different `product`

Table1:

```
+-----------+---------+
| id_seller | product |
+-----------+---------+
| 01        | 10      |
| 01        | 10      |
| 01        | 12      |
| 02        | 12      |
| 02        | 14      |
| 03        | 17      |
| 03        | 17      |
| 04        | 8       |
+-----------+---------+
```

Table2:

```
+-----------+-------------+
| id_seller | seller_name |
+-----------+-------------+
| 01        | luigi       |
| 02        | mario       |
| 03        | bill        |
| 04        | simon       |
+-----------+-------------+
```

**Output example:**

```
+-----------+-------------+
| id_seller | seller_name |
+-----------+-------------+
| 02        | mario       |
| 04        | simon       |
+-----------+-------------+
```

Comment: You must've tried something.  Include that in your question as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
select t2.id_seller, t2.seller_name
from table2 t2
join table1 t1 on t1.id_seller = t2.id_seller
group by t2.id_seller, t2.seller_name
having count(t1.product) = count(distinct t1.product)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try below

```
select table1.id_seller, seller_name
from table1 left join table2 on table1.id_seller=table2.id_seller
group by table1.id_seller, seller_name
having count(product)=count(distinct product)
```